# No WiFi, ethernet, or GPU after 'sudo apt upgrade' on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, nvidia, upgrade

I have been using 20.04.2 for a while now with no issues. I ran 'sudo apt update', 'sudo apt upgrade', and then 'sudo apt autoremove' to upgrade some packages and then rebooted.

There are some issues that are now present. My WiFi and ethernet settings do not appear in 'Settings'. I have no internet connection.

My GT 1030 GPU no longer shows in the 'About' section of settings either. It shows as 'llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0., 256 bits)'. However, when I go into 'Software & Updates' and view proprietary drivers, the proprietary driver for my GT 1030 shows up and is selected.

These may be separate issues or related. I'm not sure.

I did some digging for possible solutions but haven't had any luck.

I went into my '/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml' file and this is what is present:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

It appears my netplan settings are already default. Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:
sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e4304000-e4304fff memory:e4300000-e4303fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e4200000-e427ffff memory:e4280000-e428ffff
```

lspci response:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a308 (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation BG3 NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: Does the OS still see the network devices? Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci` and `sudo lshw -C network`? This may provide some useful information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It's been added :) @matigo

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem over the last few days (After a kernel upgrade), after trying all sorts of complicated fix it turned out installing the r8168-dkms module in the Ubuntu repositories. Since apt is obviously unavailable you will need to download it on another computer and transfer via USB:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r8168-dkms

This is for the RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller in particular, there may be another available for your QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter.